# How to remove multiple boot options from boot loader

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-10, boot, grub

I recently installed Ubuntu Linux 16.04 and right now I have multiple boot options in GRUB including some for Windows which I doubt I have much use for. I want to remove some of them. Currently on my boot loader list are:

```
Ubuntu
Advanced options for Ubuntu
Windows UEFI bootmgfw.efi
Windows Boot UEFI loader
EFI/ubuntu/MokManager.efi
Windows UEFI bootmgfw.efi sda2
Windows Boot UEFI loader sda2
EFI/ubuntu/MokManager.efi sda2
Windows UEFI LrsBootmgr.efi
Windows Boot UEFI bootx64.efi
Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sda2)
Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sdb2)
System Setup
```

How do I remove some of these options so that I only have the following:

```
Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sda2)
Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sdb2)
Ubuntu
Advanced options for Ubuntu
System Setup
```

Note that I would like my main bootup option to be Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sda2) so that if I do not specify anything, it will boot into Windows

Am new to this, so please provide instructions on how to modify the relevant configuration

Thanks!

Comment: Try installing grub customizer (I assume you want to remove some options from Grub) - it gives you a graphical interface of your grub configuration and allows you to very easily remove options you don't want.